# Property access result unused

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I just started learning Objective-C yesterday, and i can't quite figure out this warning:

```
Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects
```

Using this code (line 3 gives the warning, self.addItem()):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.itemTxt) {
        self.addItem;
        self.itemTxt.text = @"";
    }
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)addItem {
    [self.model addItemToArray: _itemTxt.text];
    _itemTxt.text = @"";
}
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: The second method in the code snippet which runs upon clicking the button

Comment: Try [self addItem]; in line 3

Comment: That removed the warning.
Doesn't self.addItem and [self addItem] do the exact same thing?

Comment: use [self additem]; instead of self.addItem

Comment: self.addItem is accessing a variable named addItem, [self addItem] is the function call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is addItem. According to your code, it seems you're trying to call that function so use this:

```
[self addItem];
```

One more thing basically, if you see in depth about IBAction, you'll find it's void. Normally, we use IBAction when we want to use IB for event fire.

So, you can use(if you need to call manually)

```
- (void)addItem {
    [self.model addItemToArray: _itemTxt.text];
    _itemTxt.text = @"";
}
```

Hope, it'll enhance your knowledge and will assist in your warning.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the syntax for calling methods vs. variables.
IBAction is fired upon a buttonclick. Thank you

Comment: IBAction and void are same and doesn't have much differnce, you can simply call IBAction methods by your own using [self method];

Comment: Anoop, the same I wrote above but for a newbie such thing are somewhat full of confusion that's why I elaborate him. :)

Answer (score 1):

To call the function use

```
[self addItem];
```

When you're using self.addItem you're accessing a variable named addItem.